# Nodejs cannot handle Elasticsearch long integers

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, long-integer, biginteger

Recently, I have faced a frustrating problem.

- As you know, In Nodejs(javascript), You can reliably use the maximum Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER, which is 9,007,199,254,740,991 without facing a loss of precision problem.
- I am using Elasticsearch for my project, and "search_after" is used for pagination. I have to fetch the sort value of the last hit and use its value as "search_after" to get the next data. However, the value of sort is [-9223372036854775808, 11763].

However, 9223372036854775808 is greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER. Because of this, I lose precision, and I can not fetch the next result.

If you need example, Elasticsearch's result is

`

```
{
    "took": 117,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 3,
        "successful": 3,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 40,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 100.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "test",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "11763",
                "_score": 100.0,
                "_source": {
                "data": "dummy"
                },
                "sort": [
                    -9223372036854775808,
                    11763
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

`

However, Nodejs parse this response as

```
{
"took": 117,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": {
        "value": 40,
        "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 100,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "test",
            "_type": "_doc",
            "_id": "11763",
            "_score": 100,
            "_source": {
                "data": "dummy"
            },
            "sort": [
                -9223372036854776000 /*Precisions were lost*/,
                11763
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

How can I get over this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Proper long-term solution #1: Wait for the "[JSON.parse source text access](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-json-parse-with-source)" proposal to become reality, then use an appropriate "reviver" function to parse the original source as a BigInt where appropriate.

---

Proper long-term  solution #2: Make ElasticSearch format larger-than-MAX_SAFE_INTEGER integers as something other than number literals (e.g. as strings), so you can manually parse them with the `BigInt(...)` constructor.

---

Short-term hack: Manually convert large integer literals to strings before parsing the JSON string, and then later fix up the object by creating BigInts where needed (or, alternatively, use a "[reviver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#the_reviver_parameter)" function). Roughly:

```
src = src.replaceAll(/(-?\d{15,})/g, '"$1"');
let obj = JSON.parse(src);
for (let h of obj.hits.hits) {
  h.sort[0] = BigInt(h.sort[0]);
}
```

Caveat: this is somewhat brittle, and it's easy to imagine situations where it won't work, but for the provided example it should be good enough.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem at your Regex, since if the data is like
`
"sort": [
                -9223372036854776323232,
                "-43434343434343434323.kkkk"
            ]
`

It will be broken while JSON parse

Comment: @FatihKurnaz Yes, for such input that could happen. You'd have to craft the regex such that it works correctly for all values you're likely to encounter -- the basic version I suggested works for the example you provided; I agree that it's not robust enough to work for any conceivable input.

Comment: Writing safe regex is complicated. But https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-bigint solves the problem by transformResponse